# How to create custom ctype for iso-8859-15 in c++

Tags: c++, locale, facet, ctype

How to create custom ctype for iso-8859-15 in c++.

Id like to use char type for internal text processing to save memory.
But needed charset is not implemented in all platforms, so i thought to implement it myself.

But i cant find any guides how to implement it.

Edit:
This code seems to work. 
But not `toupper`, how to get that working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
#define X(x) x
#else
#define X(x) (((x)/256 | (x)*256) % 65536)
#endif

const std::ctype_base::mask iso15table[std::ctype<char>::table_size] = {X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x320), X(0x220), X(0x220), X(0x220), X(0x220), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x160), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8d5), X(0x8d5), X(0x8d5), X(0x8d5), X(0x8d5), X(0x8d5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8d6), X(0x8d6), X(0x8d6), X(0x8d6), X(0x8d6), X(0x8d6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c5), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c6), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c4), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c6), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c6), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c4), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c5), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6)};
//std::ctype_base::__to_type iso15upper = {0x0, 0x1, 0x4};
const int iso15upper[std::ctype<char>::table_size] = {0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f, 0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5a, 0x5b, 0x5c, 0x5d, 0x5e, 0x5f, 0x60, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5a, 0x7b, 0x7c, 0x7d, 0x7e, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x89, 0x8a, 0x8b, 0x8c, 0x8d, 0x8e, 0x8f, 0x90, 0x91, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9a, 0x9b, 0x9c, 0x9d, 0x9e, 0x9f, 0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5, 0xa6, 0xa7, 0xa6, 0xa9, 0xaa, 0xab, 0xac, 0xad, 0xae, 0xaf, 0xb0, 0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4, 0xb5, 0xb6, 0xb7, 0xb4, 0xb9, 0xba, 0xbb, 0xbc, 0xbc, 0xbe, 0xbf, 0xc0, 0xc1, 0xc2, 0xc3, 0xc4, 0xc5, 0xc6, 0xc7, 0xc8, 0xc9, 0xca, 0xcb, 0xcc, 0xcd, 0xce, 0xcf, 0xd0, 0xd1, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xd4, 0xd5, 0xd6, 0xd7, 0xd8, 0xd9, 0xda, 0xdb, 0xdc, 0xdd, 0xde, 0xdf, 0xc0, 0xc1, 0xc2, 0xc3, 0xc4, 0xc5, 0xc6, 0xc7, 0xc8, 0xc9, 0xca, 0xcb, 0xcc, 0xcd, 0xce, 0xcf, 0xd0, 0xd1, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xd4, 0xd5, 0xd6, 0xf7, 0xd8, 0xd9, 0xda, 0xdb, 0xdc, 0xdd, 0xde, 0xbe};
const int iso15lower[std::ctype<char>::table_size] = {0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f, 0x40, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x5b, 0x5c, 0x5d, 0x5e, 0x5f, 0x60, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x7b, 0x7c, 0x7d, 0x7e, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x89, 0x8a, 0x8b, 0x8c, 0x8d, 0x8e, 0x8f, 0x90, 0x91, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9a, 0x9b, 0x9c, 0x9d, 0x9e, 0x9f, 0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5, 0xa8, 0xa7, 0xa8, 0xa9, 0xaa, 0xab, 0xac, 0xad, 0xae, 0xaf, 0xb0, 0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb8, 0xb5, 0xb6, 0xb7, 0xb8, 0xb9, 0xba, 0xbb, 0xbd, 0xbd, 0xff, 0xbf, 0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea, 0xeb, 0xec, 0xed, 0xee, 0xef, 0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xd7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xdf, 0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea, 0xeb, 0xec, 0xed, 0xee, 0xef, 0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff};

class ex_ctype : public std::ctype<char> {
public:

    ex_ctype()
    : ctype<char>(iso15table, false) {
    }

    virtual char do_toupper(char c) const {
        return iso15upper[c];
    }

    virtual const char* do_toupper(char* lo, const char* hi) const {
        for (; lo < hi; lo++) {
            *lo = iso15upper[*lo];
        }
        return lo;
    }

    virtual char do_tolower(char c) const {
        return iso15lower[c];
    }

    virtual const char* do_tolower(char* lo, const char* hi) const {
        for (; lo < hi; lo++) {
            *lo = iso15lower[*lo];
        }
        return lo;
    }

    //virtual char do_widen(char c) const{
    //}
    //virtual const char* do_widen(const char* lo, const char* hi, char* dest) const{
    //}
    //virtual char do_narrow(char, char dfault) const{
    //}
    //virtual const char* do_narrow(const char* lo, const char* hi, char dfault, char* dest) const{
    //}

};

int main() {
    std::locale my_locale(std::cout.getloc(), new ex_ctype);
    std::locale::global(my_locale);

    if (isupper('\xdc',std::locale())) {
        std::cout << " is upper--\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "not upper --\n";
    }

    for (int i = 32; i < 256; i++) {
        std::cout << (char) i ;

    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 32; i < 256; i++) {
        std::cout << (char) std::toupper((char) i, std::locale());
    }

}
```

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Standard-IOStreams-Locales-Programmers-Reference/dp/0321585585

Comment: What operations do you need to do on e.g. string types that wont work the same way with encoding unaware std::string? Maybe you don't need it at all...

Comment: As ISO 8859-15 is 8-bit single-byte (according to wikipedia), I think it's sufficient to derive from the `ctype<char>` specialization and provide your own char mask table (array) to its ctor. (This works even if your `char` is larger than 8 bit.)

Comment: I need basically all functions. (isupper isalnum isalpha isdigit islower ispunct toupper ) If possible in regex. I made `std::ctype_base::mask mytable[std::ctype<char>::table_size]` but i dont know how to use that.

Comment: Well then you need to override the member functions [`do_toupper`, `do_tolower`, `do_widen` and `do_narrow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype_char) and implement their functionality.

Comment: still no luck. Why to implement `do_widen`  and `do_narrow`?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with `toupper`? How is it called? (Can you provide an example?)

Comment: like so `std::toupper('\xfc');`

Comment: I don't think you can use this function from `<cctype>` for your purpose, as it uses the current `C` locale (it's a C Library function), whereas `std::locale::global` changes the current `C++` locale (and the `C` locale IFF the locale has a name). You can however use `std::toupper('\xfc', std::locale())` from `<locale>`. Btw, if you put an `@user` at the beginning of a comment, the user will be notified (like `@DyP yadda yadda`).

Comment: @DyP my toupper is still not working. I posted full code.

Comment: If your `char` is signed, then you have **negative** array indices e.g. in `do_toupper`. (Took me a while to figure that out ;) Also, you don't need to declare `iso15upper` and `iso15lower` as `int` arrays. Note that the result of a conversion to a signed type that is smaller than the original type (like from `int` to `signed char`) is implementation-defined. Therefore I think it'd be best to declare those arrays as `char` and look up or test what your compiler does with values like `0xFF` inside the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
#define X(x) x
#else
#define X(x) (((x)/256 | (x)*256) % 65536)
#endif

const std::ctype_base::mask iso15table[std::ctype<char>::table_size] = {X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x320), X(0x220), X(0x220), X(0x220), X(0x220), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x160), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x8d8), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8d5), X(0x8d5), X(0x8d5), X(0x8d5), X(0x8d5), X(0x8d5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8d6), X(0x8d6), X(0x8d6), X(0x8d6), X(0x8d6), X(0x8d6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x200), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c5), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c6), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c4), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c6), X(0x4c0), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c6), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c4), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c5), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c5), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x4c0), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6), X(0x8c6)};
//std::ctype_base::__to_type iso15upper = {0x0, 0x1, 0x4};
const char iso15upper[std::ctype<char>::table_size] = {0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f, 0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5a, 0x5b, 0x5c, 0x5d, 0x5e, 0x5f, 0x60, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5a, 0x7b, 0x7c, 0x7d, 0x7e, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x89, 0x8a, 0x8b, 0x8c, 0x8d, 0x8e, 0x8f, 0x90, 0x91, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9a, 0x9b, 0x9c, 0x9d, 0x9e, 0x9f, 0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5, 0xa6, 0xa7, 0xa6, 0xa9, 0xaa, 0xab, 0xac, 0xad, 0xae, 0xaf, 0xb0, 0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4, 0xb5, 0xb6, 0xb7, 0xb4, 0xb9, 0xba, 0xbb, 0xbc, 0xbc, 0xbe, 0xbf, 0xc0, 0xc1, 0xc2, 0xc3, 0xc4, 0xc5, 0xc6, 0xc7, 0xc8, 0xc9, 0xca, 0xcb, 0xcc, 0xcd, 0xce, 0xcf, 0xd0, 0xd1, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xd4, 0xd5, 0xd6, 0xd7, 0xd8, 0xd9, 0xda, 0xdb, 0xdc, 0xdd, 0xde, 0xdf, 0xc0, 0xc1, 0xc2, 0xc3, 0xc4, 0xc5, 0xc6, 0xc7, 0xc8, 0xc9, 0xca, 0xcb, 0xcc, 0xcd, 0xce, 0xcf, 0xd0, 0xd1, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xd4, 0xd5, 0xd6, 0xf7, 0xd8, 0xd9, 0xda, 0xdb, 0xdc, 0xdd, 0xde, 0xbe};
const char iso15lower[std::ctype<char>::table_size] = {0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f, 0x40, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x5b, 0x5c, 0x5d, 0x5e, 0x5f, 0x60, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x7b, 0x7c, 0x7d, 0x7e, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x89, 0x8a, 0x8b, 0x8c, 0x8d, 0x8e, 0x8f, 0x90, 0x91, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9a, 0x9b, 0x9c, 0x9d, 0x9e, 0x9f, 0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5, 0xa8, 0xa7, 0xa8, 0xa9, 0xaa, 0xab, 0xac, 0xad, 0xae, 0xaf, 0xb0, 0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb8, 0xb5, 0xb6, 0xb7, 0xb8, 0xb9, 0xba, 0xbb, 0xbd, 0xbd, 0xff, 0xbf, 0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea, 0xeb, 0xec, 0xed, 0xee, 0xef, 0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xd7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xdf, 0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea, 0xeb, 0xec, 0xed, 0xee, 0xef, 0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff};

class ex_ctype : public std::ctype<char> {
public:

    ex_ctype()
    : ctype<char>(iso15table, false) {
    }

    virtual char do_toupper(char c) const {
        return iso15upper[(unsigned char)c];
    }

    virtual const char* do_toupper(char* lo, const char* hi) const {
        for (; lo < hi; lo++) {
            *lo = iso15upper[(unsigned char)*lo];
        }
        return lo;
    }

    virtual char do_tolower(char c) const {
        return iso15lower[(unsigned char)c];
    }

    virtual const char* do_tolower(char* lo, const char* hi) const {
        for (; lo < hi; lo++) {
            *lo = iso15lower[(unsigned char)*lo];
        }
        return lo;
    }

    //virtual char do_widen(char c) const{
    //}
    //virtual const char* do_widen(const char* lo, const char* hi, char* dest) const{
    //}
    //virtual char do_narrow(char, char dfault) const{
    //}
    //virtual const char* do_narrow(const char* lo, const char* hi, char dfault, char* dest) const{
    //}

};

int main() {
    std::locale my_locale(std::cout.getloc(), new ex_ctype);
    std::locale::global(my_locale);

    if (std::isupper('\xdc',std::locale())) {
        std::cout << " is upper--\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "not upper --\n";
    }

    for (int i = 32; i < 256; i++) {
        std::cout << (char) i ;

    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 32; i < 256; i++) {
        std::cout << std::hex << i << " - " << (int) std::toupper((char) i, std::locale()) << " - " << (int)iso15upper[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This seems to work for me. Note the conversion from `char` to `unsigned char` is well-defined in every case.

I'd recommend making the global arrays either static data members of `ex_ctype` or putting them with internal linkage in an own cpp file (translation unit) alongside the definitions of the member functions of `ex_ctype`.